# Multicolinearity in logistic regression using R

Tags: r, logistic, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

Upon performing *binary logistic regression*, I have found `VIF`, using `R` programming, as follows:

```
             GVIF Df  GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
agem     2.213242  3        1.141576
eduM     2.842857  3        1.190216
eduF     2.576725  3        1.170877
ageC     1.315301  1        1.146866
diarrhea 1.031031  1        1.015397
uweight  1.129919  1        1.062977
fever    1.033433  1        1.016579
res      1.341470  1        1.158218
dis      1.440215  6        1.030866
WI       2.610752  4        1.127446
nlc      2.407934  3        1.157730
```

Based on those results, should I remove `agem`, `eduM`, `eduF`, `WI` and `nlc` for multi-collinearity? Or do I need to apply another approach? Could anybody help me?

Comment: Perhaps, you will find [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141613/31372) of mine helpful.

Comment: Three words: elastic net regression